# install output jar into local repository using pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, repository, maven-3, pom.xml

I am using maven to build the project. Output of the maven build is a jar file.

Q1. What should I onclude in pom.xml file so that it will help me to install artifact (.jar file) in my local repository? (This is for my local machine)

Q2. We are going to use JENKINS to automate the build process. In that scenario, how I would be able to install the artifact in the repository. As I have been instructed that they have two repository, one is release repository and another is snapshot repository. 
**The snapshots repository is for snapshot artifacts...i.e. artifacts that are in development.  They can be replaced and re-deployed to the repository.**
**The releases repository is for released artifacts...once a particular version has been released, it cannot be changed.  You must increment the version and release a new version.**

How do I handle above two situations using pom.xml file?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the Maven documentation? If yes, what parts of it did you not understand?

Comment: gone through the documentation..I was looking for some quick reference

Comment: I would suggest based on the things your are asking here take a training for Maven, Jenkins and may be it's worth to think about some consulting about that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply install an artifact by using the following command in your local repository:

```
mvn install
```

If you start using Jenkins you should first starting [using a repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) and if you like to handle it correctly the best way is to create a company wide pom file which contains such basic configuration like the definition of the distributionManagement:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
     <id>deployment</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://your.server.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
     <id>deployment</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://your.server.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```